# BackboneJS - Blurry background image

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I'm trying to add a blurry background image in Backbone. I have a HandlebarsJS-HTML template

```
<div class="bg" data-src="./demopics/hlowq.jpg" id="bgc"></div>
```

which i want to be rendered as a View in the Element `<div id="bgWrap"></div>`. I'm using a blurscript i found online, which looks like this.

```
//create image object
 var imageObj = new Image();

//when image is finished loading
  imageObj.onload = function() {
        //get size
        var w = imageObj.naturalWidth;
        var h = imageObj.naturalHeight;

        var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        canvas.width = w;
        canvas.height = h;
        //create virtual canvas
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

        //draw the image on it
        ctx.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0);

        //apply the blur
        stackBoxBlurCanvasRGB(ctx, 0, 0, w, h, 11, 2);

        //add grey filter
        ctx.fillStyle='rgba(64,64,64,0.4)';
        ctx.fillRect(0,0,w,h);

        //and display it in 1 second using a fade
        var $canvas = $(canvas) 

        $("#bgc").append(canvas);
        $canvas.show();
        var canvasRatio = $canvas.width()/$canvas.height();
        var windowRatio = $(window).width()/$(window).height();
        if (canvasRatio > windowRatio){
            $canvas.css({
                "height": "100%",
                "width" : "auto"
            });
        } else {
            $canvas.css({
                "width": "100%",
                "height": "auto"
            });
        }
        $canvas.css({
            "marginLeft" : -$canvas.width()/2+"px",
            "marginTop" : -$canvas.height()/2+"px"
        });
        window.onresize = function(){
            var canvasRatio = $canvas.width()/$canvas.height();
            var windowRatio = $(window).width()/$(window).height();
            if (canvasRatio > windowRatio){
                $canvas.css({
                    "height": "100%",
                    "width" : "auto"
                });
            } else {
                $canvas.css({
                    "width": "100%",
                    "height": "auto"
                });
            }
            $canvas.css({
                "marginLeft" : -$canvas.width()/2+"px",
                "marginTop" : -$canvas.height()/2+"px"
             });
        }

 };

//set the source of the image from the data source
imageObj.src = $('#bgc').data("src");
```

For some reason I dont know, this doesnt work. It doesnt create the `canvas`-element, just renders the view in the `<div id="bGWrap">`.

So the DOM looks like:

```
<div id="bgWrap">
  <div class="bg" data-src="./demopics/hlowq.jpg" id="bgc"></div>
</div>
```

But it should be:

```
<div id="bgWrap">
  <div class="bg" data-src="./demopics/hlowq.jpg" id="bgc"></div>
  <canvas some styles..... />
</div>
```

Does anyone know what the issue might be?

Answer (score 0):

I've tried your code and got error in console like below:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: stackBoxBlurCanvasRGB is not defined
```

When I commented `stackBoxBlurCanvasRGB` function call I got image rendered in canvas.

Here is a demo http://jsfiddle.net/bMxe8/ and this one http://jsfiddle.net/bMxe8/1/ with commented `stackBoxBlurCanvasRGB` function.

So you need to get working function `stackBoxBlurCanvasRGB` to make it work.